# Community Dashboards Metadata

Tags: community, dashboard

currently we are trying to make automatic deploy of our community page, but we are facing issue where, all assignment and audience is properly retrieved into xml metadata file, but we cannot find a way, how to get exact dashboard to display in component.

metadata:

```
{"componentVariants" : [ {
"id" : "40cc3587-0849-4ce4-9f3c-575eb59bc4f2",
"propertyOverrides" : {
  "isVisible" : true
},
"targetId" : "2d372dea-7f22-41b5-a4b0-84dea2ca0cc0",
"type" : "componentVariant"} ],"developerName" : "HomeES_Dashboard_3_Component","id" : "f3a3ee58-c81c-47db-855e-8aaa7c1e9922","type" : "experienceVariation"}
```

desired output is to have included name of dashboard also, so we dont need any post deploy steps to manually insers name of dashboard to display.
All references are there except name of dashboard to display.

[image: result of deploy]

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no workaround rather than manually select the dashboard and then it should load the data without any issues.

This seem to be identified as bug with salesforce with reference [W-8448451](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000oRfpQAE), W-8518671 and currently we do not have any ETA for this fix.